# Programatically setting castor properites in version 1.3

Tags: java, castor

I am trying to programmatically set the **org.exolab.castor.indent** property when marshalling some objects - however, contrary to the documentation published, the class org.exolab.castor.util.LocalConfiguration does not seem to be shipped with the 1.3 release.

Currently, I have specified the castor.properties file on the classpath, which is picking up the properties I want to set, but I would rather reduce this deployment overhead, as my indentation requirement is not likely to change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CASTOR-2304?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#action_124862). As Werner Guttmann said:

> Have a look at the `setProperty(String, String)` method on both the Marshaller and Unmarshaller classes. If you happen to be using the XMLContext class for creating Marshaller and Unmarshaller instances, there's corresponding methods.